# Where are the icons in the ALT-TAB switcher loaded from? How can I edit them?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, icons, alt-tab

On my Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon system, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switcher, in the default settings (icon and thumbnail pop up in the switcher) shows a pixelated icon for one of my applications. I do not know where the icons are loaded from, and as a result I do not know how to fix this.

So where are the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> icons loaded from into memory for the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switcher to use, and how can I resolve this issue of a low-resolution icon being loaded?

Answer (score 5):

These icons are generally located in the `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/<resolution>/apps/` directories. `<resolution>` corresponds to each resolution available: for instance, 22x22 or 128x128.

You can see what icon resolutions are available for your particular program using this command:

```
find /usr/share/ -name <application>.png
```

Here, replace `<application>` with the name of the executable for the program in question. This can be verified using the `which` command:

```
$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
$ which chrome
$
```

For instance, these are the icons available for Chrome on my system (ran from `/usr/share`):

```
$ find . -name google-chrome.png
./24x24/apps/google-chrome.png
./64x64/apps/google-chrome.png
./22x22/apps/google-chrome.png
./256x256/apps/google-chrome.png
./128x128/apps/google-chrome.png
./48x48/apps/google-chrome.png
./32x32/apps/google-chrome.png
./16x16/apps/google-chrome.png
```

Possible solutions:

1. If you don't have high resolution versions of these icons, you could try an answer suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207369/low-res-emacs24-icon-in-application-switcher) and simply create them with the GIMP image manipulator using `Image -> Scale`. Then, place the new icons in the particular directories.
2. If high resolution versions are present here but you still see a pixelated image when you <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, you can try the second answer from the previous link:

   Add `StartupWMClass=<application>` to the application's .desktop file within the `/usr/share/applications` directory.

   So for this example using google-chrome, I would add

   `StartupWMClass=google-chrome`

   to the `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of the age of this question and anyway I will provide my answer for future reference, as the one posted by @clk didn't resolve the issue for me on kde Plasma 5.2, which task switcher (ALT+TAB) was showing blurry icons for some applications, e.g. *Gimp* and *Emacs*.

In that regard I double checked the `StartupWMClass` key/value within the `<application>.desktop` file, both:

- `/usr/share/applications/<application>.desktop`
- `/home/<user>/.local/share/applications/<application>.desktop`.

The `WM_CLASS` for the app was already set to the right one, that is, the string given in output of the `xprop` command applied to the specific window of the app with blurry icon.

I also checked to have good resolution icons within `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/<resolution>/apps/` and that was not the case as hi-res icons where already there.

**Simple solution tested with KDE Plasma**

1. open the the application with blurry icon
2. click on the title bar of that window
3. choose **more actions**->**application settings**. This will open a dialog with some specific setting for the application window.
4. bottom left of the dialog, click **add property**, scroll down and choose **name of the desktop file**, from the dropdown choose **force** and within the text field, add in the name for the specific application (`<application>.desktop`).
5. click **apply**

The task switcher should now use the right high-resolution icon for the application.